# Permission denied: Missing write access to /app - docker error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, docker, npm

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV APP_URL=http://api.myapp.com
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is my docker file. I am trying to dockerize a sample react-app. I added user in group and then using that user for further commands as you can see this in second line of this code. I believe by default, only root user has access to write to these files and in order to do changes in these files, root user should not be user. Hence I created `app` user here.

But after running `docker build -t react-app.`. I am getting the following error -

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

After adding `Run ls -la` and `Run whoami` -
[image]

Comment: I didn't work. But why is it throwing this error?

Comment: In your Dockerfile, can you add `RUN ls -la` and `RUN whoami` after `COPY package*.json ./` and let us know what the output is?

Comment: I might do all of the package installation as the root user, as @AjeetShah suggests, and switch to `USER app` only at the very very end where you specify the runtime `CMD` as well.  This will let the installation run, but prevent the application from modifying its own source or assets.

Comment: Can you change this line `COPY package.json ./` ? `package-lock.json` might cause problem.

Comment: @AjeetShah Even if I use root user, when I start my application using `npm start`, `permissions denied` error is again thrown for which I came upon on this solution that we should not use root user. Plus it is not recommended as well.

Comment: @GerardSetho I have attached the ouptut in the question above. Please review it and let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @AjeetShah Just tried that. But didn't work. On running `docker run react-app`, it gave permission denied error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing this error because `/app` directory belongs to root user. The user `app` which you created has no write permission to this directory. User `app` needs write permission to install node packages (create *node_modules* directory and *package-lock.json* file).

As suggested by @DavidMaze in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980315/permission-denied-missing-write-access-to-app-docker-error?noredirect=1#comment118402965_66980315), it would be easy to do package installation as *root* user and switch to `USER app` at the last but before the runtime `CMD ["npm", "start"]`.

But still `app` user would need write permission to `node_modules/.cache` directory when running the app with `npm start` command. Hence, we need to provide the write permission to user `app` for this directory.

Here is an example that does all mentioned above:

```sh
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV APP_URL=http://api.myapp.com
EXPOSE 3000

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
RUN mkdir node_modules/.cache
RUN chown app:app node_modules/.cache

USER app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Also, note that you are running the React App in development mode using `npm start`, you might want to use a [static server](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#static-server) to serve, after creating a build.

Comment: You should also keep a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file); inside which `node_modules` and other appropriate files or directories should be added.

Comment: Yes. I do have a .dockerignore file which keeps all the appropriate files.

Comment: Hello @AjeetShah

I'm having a similar problem if you can help. This is part of my dockerfile and I use to run cypress tests inside the bash but after applying this fix I always get error `No version of Cypress is installed in: /home/node/.cache/Cypress/8.7.0/Cypress`
USER node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./cypress.json ./cypress.json
COPY --chown=node:node . .
CMD [ "bash" ]

Comment: @Mona101ma This is very old post. Can you help me reproduce this error by giving some minimal code? But it seems like you need to have `cypress` installed in your docker.

Answer (score 0):

when you create user with name "app", a new directory for this user is created in home directory "/home/app"
so,workdir should be like this:

```
    WORKDIR /home/app
```